# PDO/PHP count query

Tags: php, pdo, count

This code doesn't work but I think it's everything right.
I need to count and if there are 0 rows kick the user.

```
<?php

require 'config.php';
$email = $_POST['email'];
$codice = $_POST['codice'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT count(*) AS conto FROM primoaccesso WHERE 
    email = :email AND codice = :codice AND password = :password');
$stmt->execute(array(
                   ':email' => $email,
                   ':codice' => $codice,
                   ':password' => $password
                   ));
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($data['conto'] == 0){
    header('Location: /primoaccesso.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: and your problem is ... ??

Comment: `password` is a reserved word. Try `AND \`password\` = :password`

Comment: by the way... are you storing passwords in plain text?

Comment: @bassxzero `password` is a keyword, but not reserved.

Comment: @Lucas That's wrong. This query always returns 1 row, containing the result of `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: This code looks like it should work. Check that the variables have expected values with `var_dump($email, $codice, $password)`.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: What problem are you having? Is it kicking users that it shouldn't, or not kicking when it should?